# Multiple versions of aurelia-dependency-injection found

Tags: npm, aurelia

I want to validate form and for this, I need to install `aurelia-validation` package and register that plugin in main.js. But when I do this, I get the below warning:

> Multiple versions of aurelia-dependency-injection found:
>       1.4.2 ./~/aurelia-dependency-injection
>       1.5.0 ./~/aurelia-validation/~/aurelia-dependency-injection

Update: checked the package-lock.json and found the various version of `aurelia-dependency-injection` that used by different modules, one of them `aurelia-validation` and the other is `aurelia-cli`

Comment: May be you are importing some features of `aurelia-dependency-injection` for ,example inject class` once from `aurelia-dependency-injection` and once from `aurelia-validation/aurelia-dependency-injection`. Please check this.

Comment: As @ConductedClever also mentions, it would help if you provide the relevant parts of your `main.js` on how you actually register the plugin, including especially the import statements, and point out where the error occurs. If that helped, please share the knowledge so others can learn from it in the future.

Comment: checked it and i didnt use both of them in my project... i think the problem is in the dependencies of two modules that use the various version of the `aurelia-dependency-injection` @ConductedClever @Juliën

Comment: @Juliën  think i found the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently i had conflict submodule interference, i changed the import method from `aurelia-dependency-injection` to `aurelia-framework` and i have no warning apparently this is the solution.